# Insert string after amount of words and after the closest paragraph tag in PHP

Tags: php, string

How can I insert a string into an other string after 50 words while keeping correct HTML paragraph structure? and I mean by inserting after the closing `</p>` tag. 
Example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sint modo partes vitae beatae. Quis istum dolorem timet? Quare hoc videndum est, possitne nobis hoc ratio philosophorum dare. Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi. Quamquam id quidem, infinitum est in hac urbe; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Scripta sane et multa et polita, sed nescio quo pacto auctoritatem oratio non habet. Quod ea non occurrentia fingunt, vincunt Aristonem;</p>

< first p is over 50 words, insert string here but only after the closing </p> and not in the middle of the paragraph >

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sint modo partes vitae beatae. Quis istum dolorem timet? Quare hoc videndum est, possitne nobis hoc ratio philosophorum dare. Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi. Quamquam id quidem, infinitum est in hac urbe; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Scripta sane et multa et polita, sed nescio quo pacto auctoritatem oratio non habet. Quod ea non occurrentia fingunt, vincunt Aristonem;</p>
```

Comment: Why not use `new DOMDocument` and parse the page to manipulate?

Comment: That's one option, can you give me a head start or an algorithm so i'll know i'm on the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample like this:

```
$data = "<p>some HTML</p>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom->loadHTML( $data );

//Get the paragraphs
$paraObj = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'p' );
$para = array();
foreach ( $paraObj as $obj ) {
    $para[] = $obj->nodeValue;
}
```

Now you have the element values in an array `$para` Manipulate each array element by checking number of words(*by counting spaces*) and create new HTML.